# Can anyone tell me formula for lattice $a$, $b$ and $c$ in a hexagonal structure?

Tags: solid-state-physics

Can anyone tell me formula for [lattice constants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_constant) $a$, $b$ and $c$ in a hexagonal structure? $a$ , $b$ and $c$ are units cell of structure. As we see in cubic structure we have a formula to calculate side $a$, $b$ and $c$ method known as braggs law. So what should be the method for calculating it in a hexagonal structure. I want to define the XRD (X-Ray diffraction) structure of my crystal.

Comment: Hello! Please clarify your question .

Comment: more answer needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't understand what your question is about, but e.g. [this](http://community.wvu.edu/~mbh039/graphene.pdf) paper contains everything about the real and reciprocal lattice of a hexagonal structure (on the first 1.5 pages).

"Unit cell of structure" is not a common term; I think you are referring to the lattice constants, of which graphene has only one, not three.

Comment: If you think your question is answered, you should click the "accept" symbol to the left of this answer.

Comment: no i have not got the answer. i will do it answered when i get a conclusion.